# Microsoft Graph get basic contact (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I want to see my contact from my Microsoft account via Microsoft Graph .
code from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample
I add getUserContact function in utils/graphHelper.js

```
function getUserContact(accessToken, callback) {
  request
   .get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts')
   .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
   .end((err, res) => {
     callback(err, res);
   });
}
```

and add this to the bottom of the graphHelper.js file

```
exports.getUserContact = getUserContact;
```

and in folder routes -> index.js was modify from

```
router.get('/token',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
      graphHelper.getUserData(req.user.accessToken, (err, user) => {
        if (!err) {
          req.user.profile.displayName = user.body.displayName;
          req.user.profile.emails = [{ address: user.body.mail || user.body.userPrincipalName }];
          renderSendMail(req, res);
        } else {
          renderError(err, res);
        }
      });
    });
```

to

```
router.get('/token',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
      graphHelper.getUserContact(req.user.accessToken, (err, user) => {
        if (!err) {
          req.user.profile.displayName = user.body;
          //req.user.profile.emails = [{ address: user.body.mail || user.body.userPrincipalName }];
          renderSendMail(req, res);
        } else {
          renderError(err, res);
        }
      });
    });
```

(modify for add getUserContact at Line 45-48 in index.js file)

and then npm start at project directory

after login process the result is [image]

any solution ?

thankyou

UPDATE : 11:22   15/6/2017
update in config.js file (add contact.read)

```
scope: ['User.Read', 'Mail.Send', 'Files.ReadWrite','Contacts.Read']
```

but after authentication page it failed again[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the required scopes to access contacts. You need to add `Contacts.Read` to the `scope` value in config.js.

Comment: thank for help me but it still not working I just updated 'Contacts.Read'  to scope in config.js .  

scope: ['User.Read', 'Mail.Send', 'Files.ReadWrite','Contacts.Read']

but after authentication page it failed again